# IF Function with TimeValue

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate sick time for hours accrued. For every 35 hours a week, you get 1 hour accrued of sick time. I have the following equation:

`=IF((E46>TIMEVALUE("35:00")),"1","0")`

But it is not working for some of the values that are under 35 hours.

If it helps, once my hours hit anything over "11:00" hours, it gives me that "1" hour vacation.

[image: example of setup here]

Comment: Well, yes. `=TIMEVALUE("35:00")` is 11:00:00 AM. You can try this yourself. The `TIMEVALUE` function converts a serial number to its corresponding point on the 24-hour clock. I don't think you want that function at all.

Comment: Just to add to Alex's comment, TIMEVALUE converts text representations of time of day, not other time-related values, like hours and minutes (hour and minute values are assumed to be relative to midnight).  If you have a value that represents more than 24 hours, that's a time on a different day, and TIMEVALUE doesn't care about day counts.  So Excel throws out the extra days and just works with what would be time of day on whatever is left.

Answer (score 1):

**Either of these can solve your issue:**

```
=IF(E46>TIME(35,00,00),"1","0")
```

Or,,

```
=IF(E46>TIME(35,00,00),1,0)
```

Or,,

```
=IF(E46>--"35:00","1","0")
```

Or,,

```
=IF(E46>--"35:00",1,0)
```

**N.B.** Better use `1` & `0` without Double quotation will keep it as Number.

Comment: What, only 4 solutions?  I like the elegance of the last.  TIME() has the benefit of making the formula very clear to anyone else who might need to maintain it.

Comment: @fixer1234, actually it's two only but I have tried to show that what's the benefit of using True and False option without Double Quotes ☺ Sometimes need to work like a lay man also ☺